# Como renderizar 2 view tipadas de controllers diferentes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Como faço para renderizar **2 view tipadas** de **controllers** **diferentes**?

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Cliente cli = new Cliente();
        cli.Nome = "Al Unser";

        return View(cli);
    }
```

**Index:**

```
 @model MvcRazor.Entidades.Cliente

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = @Model.Nome;
    }

    <h2 id="teste">@Model.Nome</h2>

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Pedidos.cshtml")

    <script src="~/Scripts/Home.js"></script>
```

**Partial View:**

```
@model MvcRazor.Entidades.Pedido

<h1>@Model</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

A maneira correta é trazer tudo dentro da mesma *Action*:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Cliente cli = new Cliente();
    cli.Nome = "Al Unser";
    cli.Pedidos = new List<Pedido> 
    {
        // Lance aqui seus pedidos
    }

    return View(cli);
}
```

*View*:

```
@model MvcRazor.Entidades.Cliente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.Nome;
}

<h2 id="teste">@Model.Nome</h2>

@foreach (var pedido in Model.Pedidos) 
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Pedidos.cshtml", pedido)
}

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/Home.js"></script>
}
```